# Review page filter bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I found the following error on the question review page. To reproduce it, click on the *filter* link. This happens on every type of review.

Edit: Idem for meta.

[image]

This occurs when the explanation of the type review has been collapsed (by clicking less) or there are no items to review for that particular category.

Browser: Safari; Chrome; Opera (I haven’t checked any other, but I suspect it’s similar.)
OS: Mac OS X (10.6.8)

Comment: Same happens in Firefox on Win7. There isn't an easy way of getting around it without changing the `overflow` style of the containing div. Maybe easier to hide the filter if no issues?

Comment: am I missing something? SEems fine here

Comment: Also confirmed on Chrome 22 on Windows 7. In fact, I'm seeing significantly more of the box cut off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next build will have a fix for this styling.  Thanks for the report.